# Why would I be encountering: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class

Tags: java, security, testing, junit, web-applications

I'm getting the above error when running the following as a JUnit test. I thought it was an annotation conflict with @SpringBootTest and @WebMvcTest, so I tried removing @SpringBootTest, but was getting more errors. Why would I be consistently getting these errors?

```
package WebBasedEvaluations.configuration;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;

@SpringBootTest
@WebMvcTest
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "testuser", authorities = "USER")
    public void testUnauthenticated() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/"))
               .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }
    
    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "admin", authorities = "ADMIN")
    public void testAdmin() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/h2-console"))
               .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Removed @SpringBootTest and @WebMvcTest individually thinking there was an annotation conflict, but running as JUnit Test was failing both times.

Comment: Because you have `@WebMvcTest` and `@SpringBootTest`, they are mutually exclusive.  Looking at your test ditch the `@WebMvcTest`, also the `@EnableWebSecurity` doesn't make sense either.